# LWFSを利用しているとscript not usedという警告が出ることがある

Tags: html5

LWFSを利用していると、たまにscript not used[hoge_0_1]のような警告が発生することがあります。
放置していても特に実害はないみたいですが、何か対処法はありますでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

`"script not used"`警告は、LWFSが内部で使用している`swf2lwf.rb`Rubyスクリプトが出力しています。

https://github.com/gree/lwf/blob/0ea7bc7b1eea09eab793da10cb4feea6fb47d0f0/tools/swf2lwf/swf2lwf.rb#L4196

```
@script_funcname_map.keys.each do |key|
  warn("script not used [#{key}]")
end
```

Adobe Flash CS6またはFlash CC上で、タイムラインのアクションスクリプトパネルに以下のいずれかが含まれている場合、かつ、`swf2lwf.rb`のタイムライン解析により、そのActionもしくは埋め込みスクリプトの実行場所を特定出来なかった場合に発生します。

- SWF version 3 Action (gotoAndPlay, stopなど)
- 埋め込みJavaScript (`/* js`で始まるLWF制御用JavaScript)
- 埋め込みLuaスクリプト (`/* lua` で始まるLWF制御用Luaスクリプト)

つまり、Adobe Flashにてオーサリングするさいに、LWFを制御するためのFlash ActionもしくはJavaScript/Luaスクリプトを記述したにも関わらず、LWF再生時に実行されない、ということになります。

Flash ActionもしくはJavaScript/Luaスクリプトを記述するタイムラインを含んだムービークリップ、もしくは配置したボタンに、インスタンス名を付加することで回避できる場合があります。または、`swf2lwf.rb`のタイムライン解析を改善するために、100%再現できるflaファイルを https://github.com/gree/lwf/issues にて報告することをおすすめします。

Comment: 了解いたしました!ありがとうございます。
再現状況を調べて報告させていただきます